# Сортировка массива структур по алфавиту(Merge sort)

Tags: c++, c, сортировка, структуры, сортировка-слиянием

В файле содержатся несколько записей структур, в которых есть поле с фамилией(`char sname[50]`).Данные из файла переносятся в массив, происходит сортировка слиянием по фамилиям в алфавитном порядке. Какое условие нужно поставить в скобки( "Условие" ), чтобы произошла сортировка массива? или в том месте нужно вызывать функцию?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

struct contact
{
    char nomer[50];
    char adress[50];
    char sname[50];
};


int base_output(contact *buf, int kol_el)
{
    cout << "Полный список контактов базы данных\n";
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < kol_el; i++)
    {
        cout << (i + 1) << ".) " << buf[i].sname;
        cout << "\n" << buf[i].nomer;
        cout << "\n" << buf[i].adress;
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


void Merge(contact *buf, int first, int last)

{

    int middle, start, final, j;
    contact *mas = new contact[100];
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    start = first;
    final = middle + 1;
    for (j = first; j <= last; j++)

        if ((start <= middle) && ((final > last) || ("условие"))) //замена условия
        {
            mas[j] = buf[start];
            start++;
        }
        else
        {
            mas[j] = buf[final];
            final++;
        }

    for (j = first; j <= last; j++) buf[j] = mas[j];
    delete[]mas;
}


void MergeSort(contact *buf, int first, int last)
{

    if (first<last)
    {
        MergeSort(buf, first, (first + last) / 2);
        MergeSort(buf, (first + last) / 2 + 1, last);
        Merge(buf, first, last);
    }

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("telbook.dat", "r+b");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(f);
    int kol_el = size / sizeof(contact);
    contact *buf = new contact[kol_el];
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);
    fclose(f);
    int first = 0;
    int last = kol_el;
    unsigned int rezh = 0;
    do {
        system("cls");
        const int NotUsed = system("color 03");
        cout << "Выберите действие:\n";
        cout << "1.Показать базу контактов.\n";
        cout << "2.Сортировка по алфавиту.(слиянием)\n";
        cout << "3.Выйти из программы.\n";
        cin >> rezh;
        switch (rezh)
        {

        case 1:
        {
            base_output(buf,kol_el);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            MergeSort(buf, first, last);
            break;
        }
        }
    } while (rezh != 3);

    system("cls");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;


struct contact
{
    char nomer[50];
    char adress[50];
    char sname[50];
};


int base_output(contact *buf, int kol_el)
{
    cout << "Полный список контактов базы данных\n";
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < kol_el; i++)
    {
        cout << (i + 1) << ".) " << buf[i].sname;
        cout << "\n" << buf[i].nomer;
        cout << "\n" << buf[i].adress;
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}    


void Merge(contact *buf, int first, int last)

{
    int middle, start, final, j;
    contact *mas = new contact[100];
    middle = (first + last) / 2; 
    start = first; 
    final = middle + 1; 
    for ( j = first; j < last; j++)     //j<=last   
            if ((start < middle) && ((final > last) ||     (strcmp(buf[start].sname,buf[final].sname)<0)))   //start <= middle
        {
            mas[j] = buf[start];
            start++;
        }
        else
        {
            mas[j] = buf[final];
            final++;
        }    

    for ( j = first; j < last; j++) //j<=last
        buf[j] = mas[j]; 
    delete[]mas;
}


void MergeSort(contact *buf, int first, int last)
{

        if (first<last)
        {
            MergeSort(buf, first, (first + last) / 2); 
            MergeSort(buf, (first + last) / 2 + 1, last); 
            Merge(buf, first, last); 
        }

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("telbook.dat", "r+b");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(f);
    int kol_el = size / sizeof(contact);
    contact *buf = new contact[kol_el];
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);
    fclose(f);
    int first = 0;
    int last = kol_el;
    unsigned int rezh = 0;
    do{
        system("cls");
        const int NotUsed = system("color 03");
        cout << "Выберите действие:\n";
        cout << "1.Показать базу контактов.\n";
        cout << "2.Сортировка по алфавиту.(слиянием)\n";
        cout << "3.Выйти из программы.\n";
        cin >> rezh;
        switch (rezh)
        {    

        case 1:
        {
            base_output(buf,kol_el);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            MergeSort(buf, first, last);
            break;
        }
        }
        } while (rezh != 3);

    system("cls");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Условие - это сравнение `buf[start]` и `buf[final]` - зависит от того, как вы сравниваете... Например, если по полю `sname`, то что-то вроде `strcmp(buf[start].sname,buf[final].sname) < 0`.

Только у вас все равно не заработает хотя бы потому, что вы запутались с границами. Смотрите, вы передаете два индекса в свои функции и работаете с ними **включительно**. Но в самом первом же вызове `first` равно 0, а `last` - количеству элементов, т.е. заранее программируете выход за границы массива. Лучше использовать полуоткрытые интервалы - поверьте, так удобнее - т.е. последний параметр указывает **за** последний элемент. Тогда основной вызов в `main` корректен, но надо переписать сами функции.

**Update**

Вот как записал бы функцию `MergeSort` я:

```
void MergeSort(contact* buf, int first, int last)
{
    if (first >= last-1) return;

    int mid = (first+last)/2;
    MergeSort(buf,first,mid);
    MergeSort(buf,mid,last);

    contact * mas = new contact[last - first];
    for(int i = first; i < last; ++i) mas[i-first] = buf[i];

    int l = 0, r = mid - first;
    for(int i = first; i < last; ++i)
    {
        if (l == mid-first)
            buf[i] = mas[r++];
        else if (r == last-first)
            buf[i] = mas[l++];
        else if (strcmp(mas[l].sname,mas[r].sname) < 0)
            buf[i] = mas[l++];
        else
            buf[i] = mas[r++];
    }
    delete[] mas;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, как я поняла, выход за пределы массива только в цикле? Я исправила эти места,вот  код,варианты до исправления закомментированы. Сейчас после сортировки некоторые элементы забиваются произвольными символами, некоторые дублируются, хотя все остальные упорядочены правильно. С чем могут быть связаны эти ошибки?

Comment: Ну, я не видел исправленный код, так что откуда же я знаю?..

Comment: Исправленный код вверху сразу под первоначальным кодом, в отдельном окне

Comment: Извините, нет особо времени **исправлять** ваш код :( Я набросал быстренько свой - http://vpaste.net/macfc - надеюсь, вы разберетесь, как он работает. Сортируются левая и правая части, все это копируется во вспомогательный массив, а из него сливается в исходный - `l` и `r` - индексы текущих элементов левой и правой частей, которые сравниваются (если обе части не закончены) или просто перебрасывается без сравнения, если одна часть уже завершена. Проверяйте...